# Use bat file to run vbs command with wilds

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I put together a .bat file that asks for user input, then creates a directory and copies a `.xls` template to the newly created directory, then names the directory and `.xls` according to what was typed into command prompt:

```
@echo off
:loop
set /P MakeDirName=Enter WO number and description: 
mkdir "C:\TEST\Work-Orders\In-Progress\%MakeDirName%"

copy "C:\TEST\Work-Orders\WO-Template.xls" "C:\TEST\Work-Orders\In-Progress\%MakeDirName%\%MakeDirName%.xls"

@echo.
@echo.
set /P ask=All Done? (y/n)
if /I %ask%==y (goto :done)
if /I %ask%==n (goto :loop)

:done
@echo.
@echo.
set /P ask=Open WO? (y/n)
if /I %ask%==y (goto :open)
if /I %ask%==n (goto :exit)

:open
"C:\TEST\Work-Orders\In-Progress\%MakeDirName%\%MakeDirName%.xls"
:exit
exit
```

Now what I'd like to be able to do is after the directory and file is copied and renamed, a `.vbs` goes in and changes cell B5 to display "Work Order *"
The asterisk being the first 7 characters entered in for '`%MakeDirName%`'.

How do I make this happen?

Comment: Yes. (hint: don't ask yes/no questions unless you expect the answer to be either "yes" or "no")

Comment: Call the VBScript with the first 7 characters of `%MakeDirName%`: `cscript C:\path\to\your.vbs "%MakeDirName:~0,7%"`. Then use the argument inside the VBScript via the [`WScript.Arguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Agree, but there is another way: you could pass all the variable to vbs: `cscript C:\path\to\your.vbs "%MakeDirName%"` and then extract first 7 charaters of it inside the script with `Mid()` function: `Mid( strArgument, 1, 7)`